# Solidity How to pre-populate an Array with default values

Tags: solidity, blockchain, arrays, erc-721

My smart-contract has a `mapping` for Token-ID’s and their Prices, declared as follows:

```
   mapping (uint256 => uint256) public tokenIdAndItsPriceMapping;
```

-I intend to have only 5,000 tokens in total, and I want to pre-set their prices during the Contract’s deployment, but do so in ranges.
Here’s what I mean:

-Tokens 0 through 49 are going to be 0.1 ETH
-Tokens 50 through 99 are going to be 0.2 ETH
-Tokens 100 through 149 are going to be 0.3 ETH

etc.

I can obviously do this in the `Constructor` using `FOR` loops, as follows:

```
//  0 -- 49
for(uint i = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
     tokenIdAndItsPriceDictionary[i] = 1000000000000000000 wei; // 0.1 ETH
}

// 50 -- 99
for(uint i = 50; i <= 99; i++) {
     tokenIdAndItsPriceDictionary[i] = 2000000000000000000 wei; // 0.2 ETH 
}


// etc.
```

But with there being 5,000 values to fill, that’s still going to require quite a lot of `FOR` loops - such that I might reach the Block’s Gas Limit during the contract’s deployment - causing it to fail.
And if the project’s requirements were to change such that 10,000 Tokens will be needed instead of 5,000, what then?

Ordinarily - meaning in other languages, we can easily create a fixed-length Array and pre-populate it with default values - which would come in very handily for this.
But it doesn't look like Solidity lets you do this.

Another approach would be to create a function that’ll return any particular Token’s price using it’s ID - and a big long IF statement:

```
function getTokenPrice(uint256 tokenID) returns (uint 256) {
    if(tokenID >= 0 && tokenID <= 49) {
     tokenIdAndItsPriceDictionary[tokenID] = 1000000000000000000 wei; // 0.1 ETH
  }
  else if(tokenID >= 50 && tokenID <= 99) {
     tokenIdAndItsPriceDictionary[tokenID] = 2000000000000000000 wei; // 0.2 ETH
  }
  else if(tokenID >= 100 && tokenID <= 149) {
     tokenIdAndItsPriceDictionary[tokenID] = 3000000000000000000 wei; // 0.3 ETH
  }  
  // etc.  

  return tokenIdAndItsPriceDictionary[tokenID]
}
```

This could work - but for only one Token at a time.

What if I wanted to have a function that returns ALL the prices of all the Tokens all at once, in one big Array?
Like what if my front-end web3 App needed to get all those prices from the smart-contract as it loaded into the browser?

Answer (score 1):

In your example. You may create another map to record the init price, the key is `unint256 key = tokenID/50`, the value is the init price. Then the size of the map changes from 5000 to 100.

```
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public initPrice;
 
initPrice[tokenID / 50] = "the token's init Price xxxxxxx"
```

But it seems a bad idea and hard to updata.

Comment: Hey that's pretty interesting - I'm not familiar with this `init Price` syntax and I do like the `initPrice[tokenID / 50]` approach. Might be something there to explore! Thanks!